# Javascript Operators Issue working with Decimals

Tags: javascript, html, math

I got everything almost where I want it. My only problem is that for some reason I can't get the `bctf1` to add right. Say if `bctf = 10`, the result with the code would be `100.59` instead of `10.59`. Say if `bctf = 25`, the result with the code would be `$251.03` instead of `26.03`.

```
// BUY TOTAL
<script type="text/javascript">
function buytot(){
var bctf = document.getElementById('buyctf').value;
if(bctf.charAt(0) == "0" || bctf.charAt(0) == "" || bctf.charAt(0) == " "){
bctf2 = "0.00";
} else {
pcbctf = bctf*.029;
pcplusc = pcbctf+.30;
bctf1 = bctf+pcplusc;
bctf2 = Math.round(bctf1*100)/100;
}
document.getElementById('buyctotal').innerHTML = bctf2;
}
</script>
```

Here's the HTML with JS -> http://jsfiddle.net/hhWDe/5/

Comment: This would be so much easier to help with if we could see your HTML. Could you post that? And, ideally, a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Here's the HTML with JS -> http://jsfiddle.net/hhWDe/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You all :) This is the working code. I add `bctf0 = Number(document.getElementById('buyctf').value);` after the else and everything worked fine.

```
// BUY TOTAL
function buytot(){
var bctf = document.getElementById('buyctf').value;
if(bctf.charAt(0) == "0" || bctf.charAt(0) == "" || bctf.charAt(0) == " "){ bctf2 = "0.00";
} else {
bctf0 = Number(document.getElementById('buyctf').value);
pcbctf = bctf0*.029;
pcplusc = pcbctf+.30;
bctf1 = bctf0+pcplusc;
bctf2 = Math.round(bctf1*100)/100;
}
document.getElementById('buyctotal').innerHTML = bctf2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Force a data type on this:

```
var bctf = parseFloat(document.getElementById('buyctf').value);
```

Comment: That's because the rest of your code is treating it as a string. It's a number now. i.e. bctf.charAt(0) == "0", expects a string. Adjust your code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the String values returned by the element value properties into numbers.  Something like this:

```
var bctf = Number(document.getElementById('buyctf').value);
// OR
var bctf = parseFloat(document.getElementById('buyctf').value, 10);
```

Also, consider using the "toFixed" number method to get the "`.00` decimal places for whole dollar amounts:

```
var oneDollar = 1;
oneDollar; // => 1
oneDollar.toFixed(2); // => "1.00"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add "+" to convert a value to an integer (or float).

It will take any string and convert it, if the string cannot be converted, it will return NaN:

So your script would look like the following:

```
var bcft = +document.getElementByID('buyctf').value;
```